Does the way I sit affect how fast my bike's front tire deflates?

From past experience, front tire of my bike needs to be refilled much more often than the back tire. This is even after replacing tires, buying a brand-new bike, etc.
Does the rider leaning forward or backward have an impact on the tire pressures of the wheels? For example, assume the rider is leaning forward, applying more weight on the handlebar as shown in the figure. Which of these is true?

Front tire is more squeezed
Back tire is more squeezed
Both tires are squeezed equally

I feel like the answer is 1, first tire is more squeezed. But I also think it should be 3, because irrespective of my posture, my weight is on the seat, which is not changing.

What do you think and why?

Intuitively the tire with greater normal force (averaged over time) will experience greater pressure (averaged over time). So leaning forward or backward will definitely affect this. By how much? Or to what extent does pressure affect the rate of deflection? That really depends on the specifics of the situation.

@BobD I feel like the answer is 1, first tire is more squeezed. But I also think it should be 3, because irrespective of my posture, my weight is on the seat, which is not changing.

Off topic, but I love that you added a face to your stick character.

@AlphaLife your weight “location” is your center of gravity (COG), which is not necessarily the location of your seat. When you lean forward your COG shifts forward

It shouldn't matter.
Atmospheric pressure is 14.7 lb/sq inch. You inflate your tires to several times that. This is the force the air exerts outward on every square inch of the inside surface of the tire.
The air is held in place because the tire is strong. It resists the air with an equal inward force.
When you sit on the bike this changes slightly. The patch on the bottom flattens slightly where it contacts the road. Slightly is important because rubber flexing increases rolling friction and makes it harder to pump. The volume of the tire changes very little from the flattening, so the air pressure inside changes very little. Note that for the flattened patch, the strength of the tire contributes less to the inward force, and the ground pushing up contributes some to make up for it.
When you ride your bike, the tires will heat up. This will increase the air pressure inside much more that you sitting on the bike. If both tires heat the same amount, this should not make the front deflate faster.
So I have a couple explanations for what doesn't cause this, but none for what does.

Presumably it has less to do with the rider's position than the bike's geometry.
The front wheel is mounted on forks facing forwards, so the tyre may impact more shocks that cause small escapes of air, than the rear tyre, which is mounted on trailing parts of the frame. We know this from experience of riding a bike into a road kerb: the front tyre receives a great shock and needs to be lifted by the handlebars to avoid this and mount the kerb, while the rear tyre rides up the kerb more easily.
I am not saying the rider hits too many kerbs: it is to illustrate that all the small imperfections in the road surface will load the front tyre more than the rear.


Does the way I sit affect how fast my bike's front tire deflates?

The location of the center of mass of the rider/bike system will determine the relative load on each tire.
For a typical automobile (engine in front), the center of mass lies closer to the front tires. This increases the load on the front tires and causes uneven wear between front and back tires. This is why a regular rotation of tires is recommended.
For a typical bicycle, the weight of the rider is about 6-10 times that of the bicycle so the center of mass of the system will be dominated by the position of rider.
If the riders center of mass is closer to the front tire, then the wear will be greater and the increased load on the tire will force air out of the tire at a faster rate.

The way you are sitting has a minimal impact on the tire. The correct answer is that the front tire is more squeezed because you are putting more pressure on the front tire, but when you bike uphill, the back tire should be more pressured, so the back and front tires should lose air at the same time. My best guess is that you are overinflating the front tire, causing it to wear over time. You might need to change the front tire.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
